# Spring Boot Jersey and Monitoring URL's

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat, spring-boot, health-monitoring

We have a simple Spring Boot application with Jersey.

Spring Boot provides default monitoring end points

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-monitoring

Example:

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        // registering resources from rest package
        packages("com.xyx.abc.rest");

    }

}
```

The REST end points that are provided by Spring Boot are not available in the context of a Spring Boot Jersey Application.

The Spring Boot dependency includes Jersey, starter-actuator, starter-tomcat.

Our REST resources show up fine, but the ones provided by Spring Boot for monitoring dont show up.

E.g http://abc.xyx.com:8080/health returns a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using it as a `Filter` you need to tell Jersey not to handle those requests. E.g. by putting the Jersey resources under a separate path, like "/api/*" or something:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean jersey() {
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    ...
    bean.setUrlPatterns(Lists.newArrayList("/api/*"));
    return bean;
}
```

(from [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerConfiguration.java#L33)).

Or by declaring that your admin endpoints are "static" (via another init parameter "com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex"):

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean jersey() {
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    ...
    bean.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex",
            "/admin/.*");
    return bean;
}
```

where we have set `management.contextPath=/admin` in the Spring Boot external configuration (otherwise you'd have to enumerate all the endpoints in the regex).

You can also tell Jersey to ignore unresolved requests (instead of sending a 404). That would also achieve your goal, but might affect your client apps (if they rely on a 404 for their behaviour).

Comment: Using the following code, results in the monitoring URL's working fine when managment.contextPath=/app. But Jersey Resources give a 404 @Bean
 public FilterRegistrationBean jersey() {
  FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
  bean.setFilter(new ServletContainer());
  bean.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
  bean.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex",
     "/app/.**");
  bean.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages",
    "com.xxx.application");
  bean.setUrlPatterns(Lists.newArrayList("/api/**"));
  return bean;
 }

Comment: All the Jersey resources are as /api. However, registering the above either with /api/* or /api/** results in a 404

Comment: It should be "/api/*" (according to the Servlet spec). What are the URLs that give you a 404? Are you sure that they are mapped (without the /api prefix) in Jersey?

Comment: Still a 404 with Jersey URL's. Yeah, it is bean.setUrlPatterns(Lists.newArrayList("/api/*")); and the JERSEY URL that gives a 404 is @Path("/api")
public class HelloWorldResource { @GET
    @Path("/company/{companyId}/hello/{count}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)public HelloServiceContract sayHelloPlus(@PathParam("count") String count) { ..}

Comment: From the logs, Nov-18-2014 07:46:00.656; thread="localhost-startStop-1"; ; LogLevel=INFO ; Logger=o.s.b.c.e.FilterRegistrationBean.configure; Mapping filter: 'servletContainer' to urls: [/api/*] AND also Nov-18-2014 07:46:00.656; thread="localhost-startStop-1"; ; LogLevel=INFO ; Logger=o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean.onStartup; Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]

Comment: I changed the following to bean.addInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.xxx.application");and this seems to work. I think in Jersey 2.x , it cannot be ""com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages" and it seems to work. Thanks for your help