# Jersey v1 Spring Boot change jersey root Path to expose actuator endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey-1.0, spring-boot-actuator

starting from dsyer's example: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-jersey/tree/master/spring-boot-sample-jersey1

to Re-iterate I'm using Jersey v1 not v2.

I've noticed jersey covers up the spring-boot-actuator endpoints such as /env and /health. I followed [Spring Boot Jersey and Monitoring URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941817/spring-boot-jersey-and-monitoring-urls/26944296#26944296) to successfully re-expose the spring-boot endpoints. Now jersey ignores everything but `/hello/**` which is what I want but I also had to change the Path in my controller to `@Path("/hello")`

I want my controller code to stay `@Path("/")` and just change jersey's Application root to `/hello`. I figure I can accomplish this with the `@ApplicationPath("/hello")` annotation but I can't figure out where to put/configure that using Jersey v1 and Spring Boot. (all the examples I seem to find use `ResourceConfig` from Jersey 2 which Jersey 1 does not seem to have the same implementation)

Any ideas?

Comment: honestly I don't even have _any_ `ResourceConfig` in the code which is one reason I don't know where to put this `@ApplicationPath` annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the example you linked to (and after adding the actuator monitoring), I was able to get the endpoints to work in the following ways

1. Leave everything as is, except set the init param for the Jersey filter

   ```
   FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
   ...           
   bean.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.FilterForwardOn404", "true");
   ```

   This makes it so that even with the default `/*` mapping, when Jersey doesn't find the monitoring endpoints (which it shouldn't), it will forward the request back to the servlet container, and it will find the endpoints.
2. In your post, it seems you tried to change the URL as a work around for "shadowing" of the monitoring URLs. But the above fixes that problem without needed to change the path. But if you still *did* want to change the path, this is the solution I was able to come up with.

   It seem that trying to add the mapping in a *filter* produces the behavior you are experiencing. To get around that, instead of register Jersey as a filter, I registered as a servlet. Note that the previous solution only works as a filter. But here we will use a servlet to change the URL mapping.

   ```
   @Bean
   public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
       ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
       bean.setServlet(new ServletContainer());
       bean.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages",
                             "com.sun.jersey;demo");
       bean.addUrlMappings("/api/*");
       return bean;
   }
   ```

I imagine there should be some combination of `ResourceConfig/@ApplicationPath` that should work, but with the testing I have done, I have yet to find it. I may update this post later if I can figure it out.